# Flask MongoEngine - How to change database?

Tags: flask, mongoengine

I have Flask app with a `Post` model which spans across multiple MongoDB databases (db1, db2, db3,...), so I need to be able to query different dbs.
I'm using `Flask-MongoEngine` extension.

My `__init__.py` contains the following line:
`db = MongoEngine(app)`
and in `config.py` I have:
`MONGODB_SETTINGS = {'DB': 'db1'}`

I tried the following without success:

1. Alter the `connection` parameter in  the `db` object like this:
   `db.connection = mongoengine.connect('db2')`
   It didn't change anything. Executing `post = Post.objects.all()` still ran on the original db (`db1`).
2. Create alias in the `Post` class `meta` like this:
   `'db_alias': 'db1'`
   Then I altered the `connection` parameter in the `db` object like this:
   `db.connection = mongoengine.connect('db2', alias='db1')`
   This would indeed create a connection to `db2`, **but** I couldn't change it to another db.
3. Set `MONGODB_SETTINGS` to `{'DB': 'db2'}` and then `db = MongoEngine(app)`
   This doesn't work as well

It seems like once the model in `models.py` has been loaded (or connected to a db), you cannot change its connection.
Is that correct?
How can I change databases on the same model?
EDIT: The Django equivalent is the `using` parameter in the ORM which allows querying different DBs for the same model.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Our system uses a number of databases to host this model. This is how it's designed, so I'm pretty much constrained to the current architechture.

Answer (score 2):

As you correctly identified, a *MongoEngine* instance and consequently all the documents (models) created from it are bound to a particular database.

You can (temporarily) change the database used by a document instance *to an alias defined in the document's class* by calling the `switch_db` method on the instance:

```
Post.objects.all().switch('db1').save()
```

would save all documents in the database `db1` *if* `db1` was defined as `db_alias` in the `Post` class (otherwise you'll get a `ConnectionError`).

Alternatively there are a number of ways to make the initial configuration "dynamic" and e.g. respect environment variables:

```
import os
app['MONGODB_SETTINGS'] = {'db': os.environ.get('DBNAME', 'db2')}
```

However, from your comment

> Our system uses a number of databases to host this model

it seems that what you probably want is [Sharding](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/sharding/), where MongoDB takes care of distributing a collection over multiple `mongod` instances on multiple machines. In that case you connect to a `mongos` instead, which takes care of routing a query to the right shard. The database name is the same on each shard.